# How does this pseudocode with polynomials print 30? I realize this is a stupid question

Tags: for-loop, pseudocode, polynomials

```
n = 0
for (i = 10, i >= 0, i = i - 2)
    n = n + i
print(n)
```

I ran through this, and I got 2 instead of 30, which is correct, of course. Here's the part where I ask a stupid question: Why is it 30?

If someone could explain each step of the process to get to 30, that'd be helpful. Imagine you were explaining it to a complete layperson.

Comment: 10 + 8 + 6 + 4 + 2 + 0 = 30.  How did you get 2 as the answer, given that `n` goes higher than that on the very first iteration of the loop?

Comment: Well, honestly, I guessed - because I didn't know how to solve it. Hence my question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you would step through the code and write down the value that `n` will have as it gets modified, you'll get 30. first iteration `n = 0 + 10` makes `n` have the value 10. Then second iteration `n = 10 + 8`, makes `n` have the value 18, ...etc. I don't see how you expected 2.